# How do I use a python variable value to name a new node created in neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, bolt

I have the following line of code

`tx.run(CREATE n)` using the bolt library for neo4j to python.

I will be receiving a user input which I store in a variable, and I wish to name the node according to that. How should I approach this? Thanks

Another instance could be this. I get a CQL syntax error with this

```
    if(tx.run("MATCH(n:Player{name: playername_})" "RETURN n")):
        tx.run("CREATE (playername_:Player)")
        tx.run("MATCH(username_:User)(playername_:Player)" "CREATE (playername_)-[r:IN_TEAM]->(username_)")
    else:
        tx.run("MATCH(username_:User)(playername_:Player)" "CREATE (playername_)-[r:IN_TEAM]->(username_)")
```

The `tx.run("CREATE (playername_:Player)")` line throws up the following error

`` neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError} {message: Variable `playername_` not defined (line 1, column 22 (offset: 21)) "MATCH(n:Player{name: playername_})RETURN n" ``

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could help you:

```
playername = 'Joe'
username = 'Martin'

tx.run("CREATE (n:Player) SET n.playername = $playernamePar", playernamePar=playername)
tx.run("CREATE (n:User) SET n.username = $usernamePar", usernamePar=username)
tx.run("MATCH (p:Player),(u:User) 
        WHERE p.playername = $playernamePar 
        AND u.username = $usernamePar 
        CREATE (p)-[:inTeam]->(u)",
        playernamePar=playername, usernamePar=username)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. I am having issues getting any output/node creation on neo4j though, any suggestions as to how my connection is wrong?

Comment: No I don't, it's better to create a new question for that. Now you can accept my answer :)